# disable a checkbox before thread is sleeping

Tags: swing, checkbox

i try to disable a checkbox before sleeping but after hitting the button, the checkbox wont disable before sleeping. If sleeping is done the checkbox will disable. How can i disable the checkbox first?

```
public class Class implements ActionListener {

    private JCheckBox checkbox;
    private JButton button;
    
    public void method() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(235, 168);
        
        checkbox = new JCheckBox("checkbox");
        frame.getContentPane().add(checkbox, BorderLayout.WEST);
        
        button = new JButton("button");
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        checkbox.setEnabled(false);
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid sleeping on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread, as this freezes up your application. Instead, use a [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to wait asynchronously (see [How to use timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)). Here's an example:

```
Timer t = new Timer(0, e -> {
    // This code will run after 5 seconds
});
t.setRepeats(false);
t.setInitialDelay(5000);
t.start();
```

If you need to run a long-running operation other than sleeping, you could use a SwingWorker. Alternatively, you could run it on a separate thread and use [invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) to get back on the main thread before manipulating components. See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).